# IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: 'No module named pandas'

Tags: c#, python, pandas

I am running C# project which use result of python file. I'm using IronPython to run python file in visual studio. But the error above come up. Please help me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry you cant access third party functionalities/packages (like Pandas here)

The reason:

Pandas / numpy use great parts of **c code**, that is a no good  for IronPython (.NET).!!!!

If you need to use the power of pandas, i suggest you to create a dialog (send/reveive datas or by file or by calling an external python prog) between your IronPython Project and a program python including pandas.